# Получить значение из DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx

Используется JavaFx для создания интерфейса. В окне есть элемент DatePicker. Как получить значение типа String из этого элемента в виде строки?

Comment: toString() не работает?

Comment: Нет, ошибку выдает

Comment: а такая функция в предложенных есть?

Comment: да, была, но ошибку давала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо вам нужно это, если нет, то добавьте достаточное количество информации в вопрос.

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```